# Will "svn checkout" get everything from remote

Tags: svn

I am making a backup of all of projects from a remote svn host before we terminate our contract with the hosting provider. I am running "svn checkout" to make a copy of each project. Can anyone confirm "svn checkout" is enough to get everything of a project from remote host? If not, what else do I need do?

Comment: Maybe you want use `svndump` or `svnrdump`: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will “svn checkout” get everything from remote?

No, it will not. Subversion working copies (those you regularly create by issuing the `svn checkout` command) do not contain your project's version history. If you run `svn checkout https://svn.example.com/MyRepo`, you will get the latest version of the MyRepo repository.

> If not, what else do I need do?

If you need version history, ask the hosting provider to give you a repository dump file. See [SVNBook | Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate). You can also generate the dump yourself using the [`svnrdump` tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump). Load the dump into a new repository that you create with the `svnadmin create` command.

You can also [setup a repository replica with `svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) on your side.